# How to restrict pattern matching to the first matching file

Tags: bash

I have a very delicate bash problem:

given a directory foo

```
$ ls
foo.tgz bar.tgz baz.tgz
```

I want to generate a bash single liner, that extracts the first tarball of a pattern like:

```
bash -c "tar -zxvf foo.tgz file1" # fine
bash -c 'tar -zxvf   *.tgz file1" # oups trying to extract bar.tgz from foo.tgz!
```

Is there a possibility to restrict pattern matching to the first expanded parameter?

Refinement:

```
find -iname '*.tgz' | xargs tar -zxvf # oups! cannot add restriction to only extract file1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-quit` primary with `find`:

```
find -iname '*.tgz' -exec tar -zxvf '{}' \; -quit
```

As the actions are processed from left-to-right, this will run `tar` on the first match, then end the `find` command.

Comment: I prefer this over the other solution as it correctly covers the case where no file is found. unfortunately both solutions will not make it in to the code as it is easier to find the file in the generating code.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, try this:

```
tar -zxvf $(ls *.tgz | head -1) file1
```

You should consider what happens if nothing matches the pattern....

Comment: are you sure this is an issue? bash -c will return something >2 in this case
`$ bash -c "tar -zxvf /tmp/bar.tar.bz2 file1"`
`$ echo $?`
`2`